# Can I define a "fallback" method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it (in a performant way) possible to define "fallback" methods in JavaScript?

For example

```
function MyObject () {
   /* what do i have to add here to have my defaultMethod? */
}

var obj = new MyObject ();
obj.doesntExistInMyObject (); // I want defaultMethod to be called
obj.doesntExistEither (); // I want defaultMethod to be called, too
```

I.e.: I want `defaultMethod` to be called whenever I write `obj.calledMethod ();` and `obj.calledMethod == undefined`, but I do not want to check for `undefined` in the calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't currently have that feature. It may well in the next version, though, via [proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies). So until then, to do this you'd have to do something fairly ugly, like:

```
MyObject.prototype.ex = function(fname) {
    var f    = this[fname],
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (typeof f === "function") {
        return f.apply(this, args);
    }
    return this.defaultMethod.apply(this, args);
};
```

...and use it like this:

```
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.ex("doesntExistInMyObject", "arg", "arg");
```

(`ex` for "execute", since `call` is too easily confused with [`Function#call`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not very convenient, but probably I will have to try such a solution. Does anybody know whether exceptions are costly in JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnB: There are two aspects to that question: The cost of a `try` block, and the cost of actually throwing an exception. Modern language environments with the concept of exceptions try to make `try` blocks very, very cheap. (Very early editions of the Java VM, for instance, had fairly expensive `try` blocks, but it was identified as a major issue and fixed fairly quickly.) This is because `try` blocks are/should be part of *normal code flow*. Exceptions, on the other hand, are exactly that: Exceptions. They should not be used in normal program flow. (Not everyone agrees on that.) *(cont'd)*

Comment: @JohnB: *(continuing)* Throwing an exception tends to be costly. How costly varies and is context-sensitive, but more importantly as this is JavaScript, it's *engine*-sensitive. So there's nothing for it but to measure on your target engines. I put together tests for [the cost of `try` blocks](http://jsperf.com/cost-of-try-blocks) and [the cost of throwing exceptions](http://jsperf.com/cost-of-throwing-exception). Looks like the cost of `try` blocks is so small it falls within the margin of error of jsPerf; effectively zero cost, as it should be, across modern engines. *(cont'd)*

Comment: @JohnB: But as you can see, the cost of throwing an exception vs. (say) a guarding check is very large. Chrome can call a function that does a guarding check 27M times in the time it takes to call a function that throws just 47K times! And as you can see, other engines seem to be similar, even back to the old slow engine in IE7. So: `try` is effectively free; actually *throwing* is expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Obviously I will have to do something not very elegant.

Comment: @JohnB: For now. :-) Have fun,